# alternative to $_POST

Tags: php, post, get

I have a huge form with inputs of type (text, checkboxes, hidden et). The content of the form inputs are taken from a database. The user has to make some changes and to save the data back into the db.

At this moment I'm using a function which has a `foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)` loop. As you know, there are problems with post method:

1. can't make refresh,
2. can't go backwards.

I'll like to use `$_GET` method, but the length of my variables and values are bigger than 2000 characters.

Do you have any advice for me, about what can I do? Maybe there are some tricks in using `$_GET`. Maybe i didn't understand how to use it right?

Comment: post is not used cos GET has size restrictions.. according to the usage recommendation in the spec "GET" is basically for just getting (retrieving) data whereas "POST" may involve anything, like storing or updating data, or ordering a product, or sending E-mail.

Comment: stop crying about using POST and get along.. its your friend

Comment: @Baz1nga — it also has undesired side effects, which is why the PRG pattern is a common one.

Comment: well the PRG pattern doesnt solve all your problems.. I feels its an overkill compared to the little benefits that you gain out of it.. how many eCommerce sites have you seen use this pattern

Comment: @Baz1nga — It solves all the problems mentioned in the question (which is kinda important!), and I've lost count of the number of sites that I've seen use it.

Comment: If $POST isn't working is due your server provider blocking it. You have to go down the nightmare of setting your own `.htaccess` to allow POST to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong in POST itself. You just have to use it *properly*
An HTTP standard says you ought to make a GET redirect after receiving POST request.
So, as easy code as this

```
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
```

after processing your form will solve all your "problems"

in case you want to handle post errors, you can use POST/Redirect/GET pattern.
However it does not redirect on error, the problems you mentioned becoming negligible.

here is a concise example of it:

```
<?  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  
  //processing the form    
  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['name']) $err[] = "Username field is required";  
  if (empty($_POST['text']) $err[] = "Comments field is required";  

  if (!$err) {  
    //if no errors - saving data and redirect
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
  $form['name'] = $form['comments'] = '';  
}
include 'form.tpl.php';
?>
```

on error it will show the form back. but after successful form submit it will redirect as well.

Comment: To which HTTP version and response code are you referring to in the beginning of your answer?

Answer (score 8):

Use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Comment: I agree. Seems the best solution.

Comment: Note that [`303 See Other` is the proper redirect response](http://gif.phpnet.org/frederic/programs/http_status_codes/http_status_code_definitions.htm#s303) in this case.

Comment: Note: Many pre-HTTP/1.1 user agents do not understand the 303 status. When interoperability with such clients is a concern, the 302 status code may be used instead, since most user agents react to a 302 response as described here for 303.

Answer (score 0):

As far as loop processing goes, the foreach loop contruct in PHP makes a copy of the array you are working on. If you want to process $_POST with a different loop construct (for / while) and use functions like count(), current(), reset(), next(), prev(), end(), each(), or key(), have at it.

*Programming PHP: Chapter 5, p. 128-129*